# How to filter table based on percentile and then random sample in HQL?

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql, hue

I'm trying to random sample 200 rows from a table, but first I want to filter it to pick only top 1 percent values from a variable.

I'm getting the following error -

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:31
>   cannot recognize input near 'select' 'percentile_approx' '(' in
>   expression specification

Below is my query-

```
> with sample_pop as (select * from
> mytable a where
> a.transaction_amount > (select
> percentile_approx(transaction_amount, 0.99) as top1
>                             from mytable) )
> 
> select * from sample_pop  distribute by rand(1) sort by rand(1) limit
> 200;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Hive supports scalar subqueries the way you are using them (only for `IN`/`EXISTS`).  So move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
with sample_pop as (
      select *
      from mytable a cross join
           (select percentile_approx(transaction_amount, 0.99) as top1
            from mytable
           ) aa
      where a.transaction_amount > aa.top1
     )
select * 
from sample_pop distribute by rand(1) 
order by rand(1)
limit 200;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That makes sense, I tried your query and it worked perfect. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with the following query -

```
with sample_pop as (select a.* from 
          (
          select *, cum_dist() over (order by transaction_amount asc) pct
          from mytable
          ) a
where pct >= 0.99
)
select * 
from sample_pop distribute by rand(1) 
order by rand(1)
limit 200;
```